# Drag/Drop of image files onto Texstudio Editor

Tags: graphics, texstudio

I have installed the latest svn version of Texstudio (2.6.6) under Windows 7 and OSX Mavericks. Drag and Drop of image files (have tried .eps, .png, and .pdf) works fine in OSX but does not work under windows with the stop sign appearing indication that drop in the editor area is not possible. Any suggestions?

Comment: Please see [your questions](http://tex.stackexchange.com/users/35286/per?tab=questions). None has an accepted answer. It is not good practically to leave too many questions with no accepted answers as if no answer satisfies you and you don't leave any comment for improvement. You should reconsider which answer helps and satisfies you best and accept it. Accepting is simply clicking the check mark button below the score of any answer.

Comment: @Donut E. Knot Thanks. I have now accepted the satisfactory responses and will continue to do so.

Comment: Does the TexStudio 2.8.8 have this issue?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it appears to be about a dev-version of TeXstudio, and problems with such should rather be posted as bug-reports to the maintainer (i.e. at http://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/bugs/?source=navbar). Even if it wasn't a dev-version, it does appear to be about a bug in TeXstudio anyway, and this site isn't really the place for such reports.